# Returning HTML body from Nightmare.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I'm  currently working on some scraping with `cheerio` and `nightmare`. The reason why I'm using both and not just `cheerio` is because I have to manipulate the site to get to the part that I want to scrape and I found nightmare very good at doing those scripts.

So, right now I'm using `nightmare` to get until the part that the info that I need is displayed. After that, on the `evaluate()` I'm trying to somehow return the current `html` to then pass it to `cheerio` to do the scrape. The problem is that I don't know how to retrieve the html from the `document` object. Is there is a property from the `document` thats returns the full body?

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({show:true})
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app     = express();

var urlWeb = "url";
var selectCity = "#ddl_city"

nightmare
.goto(urlWeb)
.wait(selectCity)
.select('#ddl_city', '19')
.wait(6000)
.select('#ddl_theater', '12')
.wait(1000)
.click('#btn_enter')
.wait('#aspnetForm')
.evaluate(function(){

    //here is where I want to return the html body
    return document.html;


})
.then(function(body){
//loading html body to cheerio
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    console.log(body);
})
```

Comment: Do you require all the `html` or is `document.body` sufficient?

Comment: So far I just need the body @R.A.Lucas

Comment: Does returning `document.body` from the `evaluate` method work?

Comment: You probably want `document.body.outerHTML`

Comment: Its returning null @ArtjomB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With this worked:

```
document.body.innerHTML
```